# MS Access SubQueries

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a simple query that is selecting data from one Access table. One of the record fields is correlated to four dates in another table (named submittalfwd) through the submittalID field. I want to select the four dates as part of the query in ascending order (Date1, Date2, ...) for each record returned by the larger query.

I understand that LIMIT and OFFSET cannot be utilized with Access, so I'm not sure of the most efficient manner to select the four records in ascending order.

The query below almost works -- but MS Access can't understand SUB.submittalID in the WHERE clause.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

```
SELECT SUB.submittalID,

(SELECT TOP 1 subq2.subfwddate FROM
(SELECT TOP 2 subq2.subfwddate FROM submittalfwd AS subq2
WHERE subq2.submittal = SUB.submittalID ORDER BY subq2.subfwddate ASC)
ORDER BY subq2.subfwddate DESC) AS Date2

FROM submittals AS SUB;
```

Sample Data - submittalfwd table

```
subfwdID    submittal   subfwddate
1   1   12/9/2012
2   1   12/10/2012
3   1   12/11/2012
4   1   12/12/2012
5   2   12/13/2012
6   2   12/14/2012
7   2   12/15/2012
8   2   12/16/2012
```

Comment: Did you try to simplify that by replacing the subqueries by DFirst() or DMax() functions ? Or eventually, Allen Browne's Elookup(), which can be found here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html

Comment: Sorry for the complexity; I stripped it down to the one problematic part.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DFirst or DMax, but I'll look into them.

Comment: iDevlop -- How would you distinguish one record from the other using the ELookup()? That is, if you look at the sample data just posted in the main question, the only variable I can pass is the submittal ID number. So, I have no way of getting the middle two dates, correct?

Answer (score 0):

MS Access can't understand SUB.submittalID in the WHERE clause for Date2 and Date3 (Date1 and Date4 work correctly) because sub is out of scope when you're in the date2 and date3 subqueries.

Try something more like:

```
SELECT 
sub.submittalID, specdivision, specsection, submittalnumber, 
miscnumber, submittaltitle, subcontractor, action, comments, 
open,

min_sfDate,

(select submittal, subfwddate_min2 from
   (SELECT TOP 1 submittal, subfwddate_min2 FROM 
      (SELECT TOP 2 submittal, subfwddate_min2 FROM submittalfwd ORDER BY subfwddate ASC) s2
   ORDER BY submittal, subfwddate_min2 DESC) AS min_sfDate_2nd
where sub.submittalid = submittal),

(select submittal, subfwddate_min3 from
   (SELECT TOP 1 submittal, subfwddate_min3 FROM 
      (SELECT TOP 3 submittal, subfwddate_min3 FROM submittalfwd ORDER BY subfwddate ASC) s3
   ORDER BY submittal, subfwddate_min3 DESC) AS min_sfDate_3rd,
where sub.submittalid = submittal),

max_sfDate

FROM submittals AS SUB inner join
(select submittal, min(subfwddate) as min_sfDate, max(subfwddate) as max_sfDate
from submittalfwd group by submittal) m on
sub.submittalID = m.submittal
```

or, even better in my opinion, create 2 persistent queries for your 2nd and 3rd min dates and join them with this main one.  Easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Thanks, Beth, for the feedback. I'm not an SQL expert and your query is a bit beyond my knowledge. I'll attempt to parse your answer and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I run your query, but I'll play around with it and see if I have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that this isnt what you want, but why can't you just do the relatively simple:

```
SELECT s.SubmittalID [Submittal], sf.SubFwdDate [Forward Date]
FROM submittals s LEFT JOIN submittalfwd sf ON s.SubmittalID = sf.SubmittalID
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

?